# What IDE subprojects (=Maven <modules>) dispatching for an hexagonal project? How many jars will be in the final executable jar? Ten, tens, hundreds?

Tags: java, deployment, jar, packaging, hexagonal-architecture

Before starting to move to an hexagonal architecture, my application (roughly) had these jars, gathering into a bigger executable.

(to be more precise, for a comment below: concretely each of my *Maven* subprojects (`<module>`) has a `<packaging>jar</packaging>` kind, and at the end, the application component gathers everything into an executable jar through the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage` plugin.
If I enter with a zip tool into the executable jar, I'll see inside its `BOOT-INF/lib` seven or eight small jars of mine, among plenty of *Spring*, *Spark*, *Jakata* API jars).

**0)** Here's my dispatching of components/Maven modules/IDE subprojects, roughly, before starting the migration to an hexagonal architecture:

```
Business Object.jar

Association.jar
   . Spark Dataset
   . Association Service
   . Association REST Controller

Catalogue.jar
   . Spark Dataset
   . Association Service
   . Association REST Controller

Comptes.jar
   . Spark Dataset
   . Association Service
   . Association REST Controller

[seven others like these: Cities/Departments/Regions, Emploi,
Entreprise, Equipement, Formation, Mobilite, Revenus Imposition]

=> Those going into a Main-Spring-Backend-Application.jar 
   Inside its BOOT-INF/lib you find:
   Association.jar, Catalogue.jar, Comptes.jar...
   among other API, frameworks, drivers, used by the application.

=> Angular Web Application.war
```

Now, hexagonal architecture is splitting, for example, Association management into:

```
adapters.inbound.port.AssociationAPI
adapters.inbound.rest.AssociationController

adapters.outbound.port.AssociationRepository

adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationObjetsSociauxDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationWaldecDataset

adapters.outbound.spark.analyse.association.AssociationAnalyseSpark

application.port.AssociationPort

application.service.AssociationService

domain.model.territoire.association.AncienNumeroWaldec
domain.model.territoire.association.Association
domain.model.territoire.association.NumeroRUP
domain.model.territoire.association.NumeroWaldec
domain.model.territoire.association.RegroupementAssociation
```

I'm a newbie in hexagonal architecture. It's the first time I'm applying it, and the name of the classes and interfaces are still a bit imprecise in my mind.

### But where am I going, in term of deployment?

**1)** Should I be in front of something like that, at the end of my work, if I consider jars I intend to deploy?

```
adapters.inbound.port.AssociationAPI
adapters.inbound.port.CatalogueAPI
adapters.inbound.port.ComptesAPI
   ==> For a jar #1

adapters.inbound.rest.AssociationController
adapters.inbound.rest.CatalogueController
adapters.inbound.rest.ComptesController
   ==> for a jar #2

adapters.outbound.port.AssociationRepository
adapters.outbound.port.CatalogueRepository
adapters.outbound.port.ComptesRepository
   ==> for a jar #3

adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationObjetsSociauxDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationWaldecDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.datagouv.CatalogueDatagouvDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesIntercommunalitesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesCommunesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.AbstractComptesIndividuelsDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.communes.ComptesIndividuelsCommunesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.intercommunalites.ComptesIndividiuelsIntercommunalitesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.plan.comptes.PlanDeComptesDataset
   ==> for a jar #4

adapters.outbound.spark.analyse.association.AssociationAnalyseSpark
   ==> for a jar #5

application.port.AssociationPort
application.port.CataloguePort
application.port.ComptesPort
   ==> for a jar #6

application.service.AssociationService
application.service.CatalogueDatagouvService
application.service.BalanceCompteService
   ==> for a jar #7

domain.model.territoire.association.AncienNumeroWaldec
domain.model.territoire.association.Association
domain.model.territoire.association.NumeroRUP
domain.model.territoire.association.NumeroWaldec
domain.model.territoire.association.RegroupementAssociation
domain.model.catalogue.CatalogueId
domain.model.catalogue.JeuDeDonnees
domain.model.catalogue.OrganisationId
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.DebutOuFinPeriode
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.MetadataSource
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.NatureDonnee
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.NaturePhysiqueSource
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.Periode
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.PeriodiciteSource
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecRatioStructure
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuelsIntercommunalite
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.Compte
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuels
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecTauxVote
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.NumeroCompte
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuelsCommune
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecReductionVotee
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.RatiosNiveauxEtStructure
   ==> for a jar #8
```

It looks to me simple, but mixing every business together in each jar seems very confusing and troublesome.

---

**2)** Should I, instead, reach something like this, entirely split by business notion and by hexagonal nature?

```
adapters.inbound.port.AssociationAPI
   ==> for a jar #1

adapters.inbound.port.CatalogueAPI
   ==> for a jar #2

adapters.inbound.port.ComptesAPI
   ==> For a jar #3

adapters.inbound.rest.AssociationController
   ==> for a jar #4

adapters.inbound.rest.CatalogueController
   ==> for a jar #5

adapters.inbound.rest.ComptesController
   ==> for a jar #6

adapters.outbound.port.AssociationRepository
   ==> for a jar #7

adapters.outbound.port.CatalogueRepository
   ==> for a jar #8

adapters.outbound.port.ComptesRepository
   ==> for a jar #9

adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationObjetsSociauxDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationWaldecDataset
   ==> for a jar #10

adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.datagouv.CatalogueDatagouvDataset
   ==> for a jar #11

adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesIntercommunalitesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesCommunesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.AbstractComptesIndividuelsDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.communes.ComptesIndividuelsCommunesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.intercommunalites.ComptesIndividiuelsIntercommunalitesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.plan.comptes.PlanDeComptesDataset
   ==> for a jar #12

adapters.outbound.spark.analyse.association.AssociationAnalyseSpark
   ==> for a jar #13

application.port.AssociationPort
   ==> for a jar #14

application.port.CataloguePort
   ==> for a jar #15

application.port.ComptesPort
   ==> for a jar #16

application.service.AssociationService
   ==> for a jar #17

application.service.CatalogueDatagouvService
   ==> for a jar #18

application.service.BalanceCompteService
   ==> for a jar #19

domain.model.territoire.association.AncienNumeroWaldec
domain.model.territoire.association.Association
domain.model.territoire.association.NumeroRUP
domain.model.territoire.association.NumeroWaldec
domain.model.territoire.association.RegroupementAssociation
   ==> for a jar #20

domain.model.catalogue.CatalogueId
domain.model.catalogue.JeuDeDonnees
domain.model.catalogue.OrganisationId
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.DebutOuFinPeriode
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.MetadataSource
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.NatureDonnee
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.NaturePhysiqueSource
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.Periode
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.PeriodiciteSource
   ==> for a jar #21

domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecRatioStructure
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuelsIntercommunalite
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.Compte
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuels
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecTauxVote
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.NumeroCompte
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuelsCommune
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecReductionVotee
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.RatiosNiveauxEtStructure
   ==> for a jar #22
```

It's yet the situation where I am, having started the migration, and I have this tree of subprojects, now:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Summary for Application : Extraction et analyse de données par Apache Spark :

POM Parent ......................................... SUCCESS
Domain-Core : Utilitaires bas niveau et mécanismes techniques des objets métiers SUCCESS
Domain : Objets métiers ............................ SUCCESS
Application-Port : Association ..................... SUCCESS
Adapter-Inbound-Port : Association ................. SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Port : Association ................ SUCCESS
Application-Service-Core : Classes de base des services Spring SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Dao : DAO pour Postgis (Général) .. SUCCESS
POM Parent pour les projets Spark .................. SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Core : Classes de bases et utilitaires Spark SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Catalogue data.gouv.fr SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Maillage territorial (COG) SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Registre National des Associations (RNA) SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Comptes communaux et intercommunaux SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Emploi/Chômage .... SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Entreprises et établissements SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Base équipement INSEE SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Formation, enseignement, diplômes SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Mobilité .......... SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Dataset : Revenus (salaires, retraites) et imposition des ménages SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Analyse : Association ....... SUCCESS
Adapter-Outbound-Spark-Analyse : Impacts communaux . SUCCESS
Adapter-Inbound-Rest : Association ................. SUCCESS
Application-Service : Gestion des associations ..... SUCCESS
Application-Backend métier : Services d'enrichissement Open Data SUCCESS
Adapter-Inbound-Rest : Génération clients OpenAPI des services métiers (Général) SUCCESS
Adapter-Inbound-Web : Présentation des données ..... SUCCESS
Application : Extraction et analyse de données par Apache Spark SUCCESS 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  16.331 s
Finished at: 2023-05-03T16:18:40+02:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I have only extracted the first business family/notion: Association.
Doing the other (Mobility, Tax, City...) will lead me to an impressive number of jars/a lot of subprojets.
I will quickly have hundred of modules/jars/ide projects in my redispatched application.

---

**3)** Or dispatching only by hexagonal global nature, and then: business notion?

```
adapters.inbound.port.AssociationAPI
adapters.inbound.rest.AssociationController
   ==> for a jar #1

adapters.inbound.port.CatalogueAPI
adapters.inbound.rest.CatalogueController
   ==> for a jar #2

adapters.inbound.port.ComptesAPI
adapters.inbound.rest.ComptesController
   ==> for a jar #3

adapters.outbound.port.AssociationRepository
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationObjetsSociauxDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.association.AssociationWaldecDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.analyse.association.AssociationAnalyseSpark
   ==> for a jar #4

adapters.outbound.port.CatalogueRepository
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.datagouv.CatalogueDatagouvDataset
   ==> for a jar #5

adapters.outbound.port.ComptesRepository
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesIntercommunalitesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.balance.communes.BalanceComptesCommunesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.AbstractComptesIndividuelsDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.communes.ComptesIndividuelsCommunesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.individuel.intercommunalites.ComptesIndividiuelsIntercommunalitesDataset
adapters.outbound.spark.dataset.plan.comptes.PlanDeComptesDataset
   ==> for a jar #6

application.port.AssociationPort
application.service.AssociationService
   ==> for a jar #7

application.port.CataloguePort
application.service.CatalogueDatagouvService

application.port.ComptesPort
application.service.BalanceCompteService
   ==> for a jar #8

domain.model.territoire.association.AncienNumeroWaldec
domain.model.territoire.association.Association
domain.model.territoire.association.NumeroRUP
domain.model.territoire.association.NumeroWaldec
domain.model.territoire.association.RegroupementAssociation
domain.model.catalogue.CatalogueId
domain.model.catalogue.JeuDeDonnees
domain.model.catalogue.OrganisationId
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.DebutOuFinPeriode
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.MetadataSource
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.NatureDonnee
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.NaturePhysiqueSource
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.Periode
domain.model.catalogue.metadata.PeriodiciteSource
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecRatioStructure
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecMoyenneStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuelsIntercommunalite
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.Compte
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtReductionVotee
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtRatioStructureEtStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecStrateEtTauxVoteEtStrate
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesTotalOuBaseEtParHabitant
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuels
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecTauxVote
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.NumeroCompte
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.ComptesIndividuelsCommune
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.ComptesAvecReductionVotee
domain.model.territoire.comptabilite.comptesIndividuels.RatiosNiveauxEtStructure
   ==> for a jar #9
```

Here, the number of submodules would be reduced, but outbound adapters jars [per kind of business notion] could see at the end a mix of *Spark*, *Postgresql*, etc. inside, and for the adapters.inbound, I could find myself having rest, angular application, etc. gathered.

And how could I check their boundaries, if I'll become meticulous and wish to manage them through the Java 9 module system?

It would be odd, also.

Comment: What’s your goal? Why do you need more than one JAR per deployable unit?

Comment: @TimMoore it's a matter of subprojects if you prefer. I've started with a Maven project having roughly eight `<module>` of `<packaging>jar</packaging>` kind, gathered into a final executable through the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage` plugin => I have, for backend, a single executable jar, but if I open it with a tool its `BOOT-INF/lib` has seven small jars of mine inside, among plenty of _Spring_, _Spark_, _Jakata_ API jars. What I'm fearing now, is to be going to hundred of these modules.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example of Hexagonal Architecture with Java 9 modules:

- One for the app (hexagon).
- One for each adapter.
- One for a startup that builds the whole system.

Github repo with the code:

https://github.com/jmgarridopaz/bluezone